Why doesn't lsp(language server protocol) work in the terminal?
'lcp' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
When I try to run it, this error appears in the terminal.
lsp is installed. I work in webstorm
I removed lsp, rebuilt the project and removed dependencies, but it didn't help.

LSP is an protocol, not a executable. What exactly are you trying to do?

@tkausl When I run this command - "proxy": "lcp --proxyUrl http://localhost:8080/" this problem appears, but I don't understand what can be done about it.
